# Reference of similar functions between Programming Languages

Tags: reference, programming-languages, correlated

I'm wondering is there is a compiled knowledge base of similar functions or functionalities between several programming languages. The reason I'm asking this question is due to the fact that one is learning a new programming language and has extensive knowledge of another, it's often difficult to know or imagine the correlation of functions between those two languages.

Obviously, if such reference exists, it would make learning a new language much easier since one only had to lookup the similar function and eventually memorize it.

Comment: you are asking about similarities of functions vs similarities of language operations. which of these is closest to what you are asking: how do you merge elements of 2 arrays, or find the length of a string, or generate a truecolor bitmap, or open, write, close a file, or read a row from a database?

I think just comparing syntaxs is not going to offer much leverage in moving between languages

Comment: Actually it might make some things more difficult, especially subtle syntax differences. It would be better to see how certain large features are sort of similar, to see how patterns in language A could be applied in language B.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/mw/index.php?title=Main_Page) - user-edited wiki focused on implementing tasks in different languages
- [Syntax across languages](http://merd.sourceforge.net/pixel/language-study/syntax-across-languages/) - more focused on syntax
- [Wikipedia: Comparison of programming languages (basic instructions)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(basic_instructions))

Answer (score 4):

[Syntax across languages](http://merd.sourceforge.net/pixel/language-study/syntax-across-languages/) is the best one. It catalogs control structures, data types, libraries, comments, and much more. Includes information about Delphi, SML, OCaml, Java, Smalltalk, C++, Ruby, Perl, Python, Lisp, PL/I, PHP, EmacsLisp, and VisualBasic.

Answer (score 0):

[The original wiki](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki) is quite good because its a free flowing discussion(It's not meant to be a rule based encyclopedia like wikipedia) of programming, which with its focus on history, meandering ways, flame wars, and language fanboyism (all in good fun) tells a lot about how features x in language A is basically/better/sort of equivalent to feature y in language B.